# Sort list with insertion sort to get max number combined from list elements (python)

Tags: python, sorting, max

Got a task of sorting input list to combine max number from elements, first input number is len of list. I have to concatenate all the numbers in the input, such that the result expresses the largest possible number expressible with the given input numbers

Example input output:

```
38
82 58 66 34 64 37 40 97 93 52 28 98 90 64 19 22 21 83 56 70 46 17 31 51 55 41 68 18 98 89 88 74 6 6 31 36 35 8

9898979390898888382747068666664645856555251464140373635343131282221191817

6
9 10 1 1 1 6

9611110
```

My idea is using distinct compare func out of insertion sort func, and thats what i got so far:

```
def is_max(val1, val2):
    a = [int(i) for i in str(val1)]
    b = [int(i) for i in str(val2)]
    if len(a) == 1 or len(b) == 1:
        if a[0] > b [0]:
            return True
    a = a[::-1]
    b = b[::-1]
    while len(a) > 1 and len(b) > 1:        
        if a.pop() < b.pop():
            return True
        else: return False

def ins_sort_by_compare(arr, max):
    for i in range(1, len(arr)):
        item_to_insert = arr[i]
        j = i
        while j > 0 and max(item_to_insert, arr[j-1]):
            arr[j] = arr[j-1]
            j -= 1
        arr[j] = item_to_insert
        print(f'step {i}, sorted {i+1} elements: {arr}') 
    return arr

def read_input():
    n = input().split()
    list = [int(x) for x in n]
    return list

def main():
    b = int(input())
    res = ins_sort_by_compare(read_input(), is_max)
    q = ''
    for i in res: 
        q += str(i)
    print(q)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

My input and output:

```
6
9 10 1 1 1 6

9610111

38
82 58 66 34 64 37 40 97 93 52 28 98 90 64 19 22 21 83 56 70 46 17 31 51 55 41 68 18 98 89 88 74 6 6 31 36 35 8

9793989098828389888707466646468665852565155404641343731313635282221191718
```

I cant get exact same numbers, just dont get how act if digits in numbers are equal or count of digits in number is not same, so need some assistance.

Comment: Hi can you please explain bit more about your output logic?

Comment: Still no idea what you're actually trying to sort by…

Comment: @Stackpy So we get list of numbers from input and output should be max number possible, combined from input numbers from list

Comment: @deceze i am trying to sort by using insertion sort

Comment: What exactly does "max number possible" mean?

Comment: You simply want to *concatenate* all the numbers in the input, such that the result expresses the largest possible number expressible with the given input numbers?

Comment: @deceze sorry for my english(  i have to find the combination of numbers in list, so when  you join them the output is biggest number

Comment: @deceze excactly, thats the right word

Comment: @Stackpy i need concatenate all the numbers in the input, such that the result expresses the largest possible number expressible with the given input numbers